# Does anyone have a smart contract that allows me to send to many recipients at once?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I just started using ethereum, so im not sure how smart contracts work and if this would be possible. Id like to be able to send ether and also cob from one account to a few hundred other accounts in a certain amount.

Can anyone help me with this? I need detailed instructions as im really new to this. thank you!

Comment: the best i can do with the little knowlege i have of c++ is to make a function that keeps calling the next element of a vector using a for loop.

Id need a huge vector with all the addresses put into it (vectorname[1...2..3...] = first address, second, third, etc

I really have never made a smart contract so i dont know anything really further than what i know about how id implement  a regular c++ program

Comment: callnextaddress string(vector<string> addresses){

for (i=0; i<addresses.size(); i++){

what would i write in here to make it send a certain amount to each recipient? or am i on a totally wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you want exactly, but I've written a small smart contract for the case where you're sending Ether to a certain group of addresses regularly:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SendToMany
{
    address[] public recipients;

    function SendToMany(address[] _recipients) public
    {
        recipients = _recipients;
    }

    function() payable public
    {
        uint256 amountOfRecipients = recipients.length;
        for (uint256 i=0; i<amountOfRecipients; i++)
        {
            recipients[i].transfer(msg.value / amountOfRecipients);
        }
    }
}
```

Steps to use it:

- Deploy the contract with the array of recipients you want as argument
- Simply send funds to the address of your deployed contract. The contract will automatically divide the Ether you sent and send an equal amount to each specified recipient.

  Make sure you use a high enough gas limit when sending funds to the contract. (a reasonable limit is `20000 * amount of recipients`)

You can see this system in action here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9b4df27076ea41ab082584999be8d07e923217a3ae4527069f7786f07674b7e

I sent `0.00369` to the contract. The contract immediately transferred `0.00123` to all 3 recipients.

Disclaimer: I cannot be held responsible for lost funds.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was hoping for. Is there a way to also send tokens with it?

Also how do i add the recipients here? where would i put the arguments or addresses  in the code and what would it look like? Ive only started learning c++ and this all looks sort of new to me.

Comment: Asking someone to write a fully-functioning smart contract is pretty out of scope for this site. You probably want to get comfortable with basic coding principles before you start tackling the blockchain, as there are many advanced concepts that aren't going to make sense to you.